# Why does the following for loop do not work fine?

Tags: c, char

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char ch;
    for(ch='0';ch<=127;ch++)
    printf("%c %d",ch,ch);
    return 0;
}
```

How ever this becomes an infinite loop when executed. I want to know exact reason behind it? Is type casting to and fro from int to char the reason?

Also one small question

Whether all files having .c extension are required to have `main()` in all of them??

Comment: Your system uses signed `char`s in the range from -128 to 127. That means that `ch <= 127` is always true by definition. A quick solution here is to use `int` instead of `char`.

Comment: Hint:  go to an ASCII table and check what **number** the 0 **character** is

Comment: Check the value of `CHAR_MAX` on your platform.

Comment: Did you bother to look at the *values* printed in that infinite loop. That should tell you something. The moment `ch == 127` and a subsequent increment occurs, an overflow condition arises if `char` is signed. (and like most implementations, yours is indeed signed).

Comment: As to your second question: There should be just one `main` for each program; `main` is the function that gets called from the operating system. If you have many `*.c` files that corresond to a small program each, each of them should have a `main` routine. If you have many `*.c` files that should be linked into a single big program, only one of them should provide the `main` function.

Comment: @MOehm Thank you for the answer (y)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, you are comparing `char` to `int`

```
for(ch='0';ch<=127;ch++)
```

int value of a char can range from 0 to 255 or -128 to 127, depending on implementation.

In your case, a `char` is a `signed char`, which can hold the value of a range to -128 to +127. Therefore once the value reaches 127 in your case, it overflows and you get negative value and loop continues forever, because it's value will never become more than 127.once it reaches 127, in next iteration the value will be -128, and the loop continues.

You can use `unsigned char ch;`

Comment: Thank you Nishant... it was going on printing some characters in the output. It was overflowing as u said.

Comment: It's not necessarily from 0 to 255 or -128 to 127 because `CHAR_BIT` may be larger than 8

Answer (score 2):

Along with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043600/2173917) already given by [Mr. Nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307255/nishant), I would like to add that, indeed, for your platform, `char` being a `signed` type, in case of

```
for(ch='0';ch<=127;ch++)
```

when `ch` holds a value *equal to* 127, then the loop condition satisfies, control enters the body, and after the body has been executed, `ch++` is executed.

Now, essentially, here you're *overflowing* a signed type, and the resultant action is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thank you helping me in understanding

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exaclty what nishant said above, you can change your code like this to execute that

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    char ch;
    for(ch='0';abs(ch)<=127;ch++)
    printf("%c %d",ch,ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One change required in your code - Change of `char ch` to `unsigned char ch`

```
unsigned char ch;
for(ch='0';ch<=127;ch++)
    printf("%c %d\n",ch,ch);
return 0;
```

This is happening due to the fact that char value ranges from -128 to +127, and when you increment by 1 from 127, it becomes -128.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(ch='0';ch<=127;ch++)
```

The max of char is 127, so `ch <= 127` will never end. It's always True.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed above max is 127 so the loop goes infinite.
Main function is required for each and every c program Other wise compiler doesn't identify which block execute first and what to do...!!